# Edit files with Google Docs but store them locally in home folder

Tags: google-drive

How can I use Google Docs/Drive to be able to work on and edit files using the app but have the files stored on and accessed from my local machine?

I see many many benefits to Google Docs - the access-everywhere, in-browser, collaboration etc. The only problem is I want the files on my local hard drive. I'm not concerned about the privacy; I just want all my data in one place rather than some locally and some hosted. This includes being able to choose which folder a document is stored in.

If it's not possible via Google Docs then I'm open to what other options I may have in browser-based document editor where I store the files in my local folder structure.

Comment: I don't think Google Drive supports offline access on all operating systems yet. But when it does, I think it might meet most of your requirements? What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

There's [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/), which is a GPL collaboration verion of Google Docs. There are various example implementations which protect the privacy of your documents, although privacy isn't the issue.

Comment: I have seen Etherpad, but as far as I can tell it doesn't let you choose where each file is stored on your hard drive. Unless you know otherwise?

Comment: It's a pretty trivial code change to save/open using the local hard disk, though needs something on the server to echo the file to support all major browsers. Either get an in-house developer to change it, or if you don't have devs, see if someone familiar with Etherpad wants a contract to make the change.